# Anaconda doesn't list package installed by pip

Tags: python, pip, conda

I'm trying to setup `elasticsearch` package on my system.

It isn't available through `conda install` - package is missing in current linux-64 channels.

So I installed it via system pip, and that works fine:

```
$ which pip2
/usr/bin/pip2
$ sudo pip2 install elasticsearch
...
$ pip2 list | grep ela
elasticsearch (2.4.0)
elasticsearch-dsl (2.1.0)
```

But when I try it through the conda's pip:

```
$ which pip
/home/michal/Bin/anaconda/envs/raptor/bin/pip
$ pip list | grep ela
$
```

it doesn't show up. That kind of makes sense, since I did it through the system.

But if I try to install it:

```
$ sudo pip install elasticsearch
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): elasticsearch in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

it is already set-up, but I cannot list it either in `pip list` nor in `conda list`. If I'm not in conda env, packages import in system python, but in conda env the packages cannot be imported.

Okay, it is in the system. But how can I force it to install into conda? I already tried to uninstall the system conda and install it via conda pip, but it again puts it into `usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/elasticsearch/`

My conda info:

```
$ conda info -a
Current conda install:

             platform : linux-64
        conda version : 4.1.6
    conda-env version : 2.5.1
  conda-build version : 1.21.3
       python version : 3.5.2.final.0
     requests version : 2.10.0
     root environment : /home/michal/Bin/anaconda  (writable)
  default environment : /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/envs/raptor
     envs directories : /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/envs
        package cache : /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/pkgs
         channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
          config file : /home/michal/.condarc
         offline mode : False
    is foreign system : False

# conda environments:
#
raptor                *  /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/envs/raptor
tensorflow               /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/envs/tensorflow
root                     /home/michal/Bin/anaconda

sys.version: 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default...
sys.prefix: /home/michal/Bin/anaconda
sys.executable: /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/bin/python3
conda location: /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda
conda-build: /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/bin/conda-build
conda-convert: /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/bin/conda-convert
conda-develop: /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/bin/conda-develop
conda-env: /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/bin/conda-env
conda-index: /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/bin/conda-index
conda-inspect: /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/bin/conda-inspect
conda-metapackage: /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/bin/conda-metapackage
conda-pipbuild: /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/bin/conda-pipbuild
conda-render: /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/bin/conda-render
conda-server: /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/bin/conda-server
conda-sign: /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/bin/conda-sign
conda-skeleton: /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/bin/conda-skeleton
user site dirs: ~/.local/lib/python2.7
                ~/.local/lib/python3.4

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: raptor
CONDA_ENVS_PATH: <not set>
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: <not set>
PATH: /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/envs/raptor/bin:/home/michal/Bin/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/michal/.rvm/bin:/home/michal/Bin:/home/michal/.rvm/bin
PYTHONHOME: <not set>
PYTHONPATH: :/home/michal/Code/BSS/fairalgo/src:/home/michal/Code/BSS/fairalgo/src

WARNING: could not import _license.show_info
# try:
# $ conda install -n root _license
```

---

edit:
By using `sudo` it does indeed use different pip, I didn't realize that:

```
root@mentat:/home/michal/Bin/anaconda# which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

When I use pip without sudo, it crashes:

```
$ pip install elasticsearch
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 236, in run
    session = self._build_session(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 52, in _build_session
    session = PipSession()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 216, in __init__
    super(PipSession, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 272, in __init__
    self.headers = default_headers()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/utils.py", line 555, in default_headers
    'User-Agent': default_user_agent(),
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/utils.py", line 524, in default_user_agent
    _implementation = platform.python_implementation()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 1521, in python_implementation
    return _sys_version()[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 1486, in _sys_version
    repr(sys_version))
ValueError: failed to parse CPython sys.version: '2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jun 15 2016, 15:21:30) \n[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]'

Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpUvOaDo
```

Please help, I am totally lost in this.

Comment: I think that `sudo pip` may get a different version of pip - not the anaconda one.  You shouldn't need `sudo` to install into your home directory anyway.

Comment: use `/path/to/python -m pip [commands]` instead of just `pip [commands]` to be sure you are installing for the right interpreter

Comment: Oh, ok. Good point about I shouldn't need sudo for that, that's what I found weird as well. If I don't use sudo, pip crashes (I updated  the original post)

Comment: You are still running the wrong pip. Look at the paths in the stacktrace - they are all pointing to the system version of Python. Try the first command @Julius suggested, see if it helps.

Comment: @darthbith I get the same error: 

 
 $ /home/michal/Bin/anaconda/envs/raptor/bin/python -m pip install elasticsearch
 ...
 ValueError: failed to parse CPython sys.version: '2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jun 15 2016, 15:21:30) \n[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]'

Comment: Just in case, try reinstalling `pip` into that environment: `source activate raptor && conda remove pip && conda install pip && pip install elasticsearch`